# Bash script to connect to a remote server, and pull the last time a file was modified

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am looking to create a bash script to query a remote server for the last time every instance of a file was modified.  Each home directory has a version of this file.

For example, both `owner` and `owner1` have a copy of `foo.txt` in their home directories on a remote box accessible via `ssh`.

```
/home/owner/
-rw-r--r--  1 owner owner   3368 Jul  29  2014 foo.txt

/home/owner1/
-rw-r--r--  1 owner1 owner1   3368 Jul  28  2014 foo.txt
```

I would like to output this information to a file that would look like:

```
User: owner  Last Modified: Jul 29 2014
User: owner1  Last Modified: Jul 28 2014
```

Comment: You are going to want the `stat` and `date` commands for this. Possibly also `printf`/`echo`.

Answer (score 2):

You really ought to at least show that you attempted to write the script youself. Anyway, it's only a one-liner, so why quibble:

```
ssh remote-box 'ls -l /home/*/foo.txt'
```

It's not precisely the format you suggested, but it has all the information you asked for.

Comment: Perhaps `ssh remote-box stat -c "User: %U Last Modified: %y" /home/*/foo.txt`... Although the modification date is probably not in exactly the right format - not sure there's an easy fix for that...

Answer (score 0):

The following function will print the data you're looking for:

```
remote_mod() {
  ssh $1 ls -l $2 | awk '{ print "User: "$3"  Last Modified: "$6" "$7" "$8 }'
}
```

This prints something like:

```
$ remote_mod yourmachine '~/.bashrc'
User: root  Last Modified: Jun 2 15:01
```

You can then do this in a loop if you want to run the command against multiple remote files:

```
for d in owner owner1
do
  remote_mod yourmachine /home/$d/foo.txt
done
```

The `stat` command will give you even more information, but it's in a more verbose format.

Comment: stat -c"User %U Last modified:%y" would do.

Comment: @Tony that's what I get for looking at `stat`'s manpage on my mac, rather than on Linux.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, maybe not exactly the output you want but I'm sure you will be able to modify the script to suit your needs. Make sure the user you ssh with have read access to the home directories.

```
ssh HOSTNAME "find /home/  -maxdepth 2 -name foo.txt | xargs -l -I{} bash -c '{
DIR=\$(dirname {});
LAST=\$(stat -c %y {});
echo "Dir:\${DIR} Last Modified :\${LAST}" 
}'"
```

If the owner of the file is the "user" you want to be printed, you can simplify with :

```
ssh HOSTNAME "find /home/  -maxdepth 2 -name foo.txt | xargs -l -I{} bash -c '{
stat -c \"User: %U Last Modified : %y\" {}; 
}'"
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect.  Thank you, Tony!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo owner: `ssh owner@remote-box "date -r foo.txt"`>output.txt
echo owner1: `ssh owner1@remote-box "date -r foo.txt"`>>output.txt
```